# mysql calling another procedure(of another schema) from procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to call a SP1 from a SP2.
SP1 is stored in Another database schema on same PC.
Please check following Snippet

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`  PROCEDURE `db2`.`sp2_procedure` ()
BEGIN
    call sp1_procedure(50);
END
```

Also tried `call db1.sp1_procedure(50);`
Is it i am calling Wrongly or Calling SP of Other schema is not possible

**Note :: SP - Stored Procedure**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply, just mention schema name in prefix.

For instance :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `db1`.`sp1`()
BEGIN
select 'I am procedure from another db';
END
```

Next,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `db2`.`sp2`()
BEGIN
call db1.sp1();
END
```

And call that like so :

```
use db2;
call `db2`.sp2();
```

Comment: It will work without `use db2` because we mentioned it before sp name.